# Collapsing spaces in resource file in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, resources, whitespace

I use the following for page title and I want to show `n` number of white spaces after page title.

```
<data name="PageResource1.Title" xml:space="preserve">
   <value>My Page Title                                                                                             </value>
</data>
```

But the spaces are rendered as a single space. :(

I can not use non-breakable space in resx file. I get following

[image]

Comment: Can't you use `&nbsp;` repeated the requiered number of times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `&nbsp;` instead of white space.
`<value>My Page Title&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;...`

Comment: Yea. Of course. But is it a good method to read the resource content from its OWN resource file ?

Comment: I tried this `string title = GetLocalResourceObject("PageResource1.Title").ToString();
            this.Title = title + 50spaces;`. But NOT worked.

Comment: Assuming you read that value is `string s` then you can do `your_value = s.Replace(" ", @"&nbsp;");`

Answer (score 6):

You can't use `&nbsp;` in an xml file as it's not a recognised entity. It's also content that's encoded into the xml file. The xml file needs to store the double encoded value.

You need to use either: `&amp;nbsp;` or `<![CDATA[&nbsp;]]>`

Answer (score 0):

Use `&nbsp;` to represent a space.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a problem with resources or even ASP.NET. You need what they call a [non-breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space). Replace the spaces in the resource file with `&nbsp;` and it will work fine.

Quoted somewhat freely from the wiki page:

> It prevents the “collapsing” of multiple consecutive whitespace
>   characters into a single space.

Answer (score 0):

Better is to use the [Character entity reference(&nbsp)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_entity_reference) for including a white space any where in asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem myself.

The Hexadecimal representation of `&nbsp` is A0. Meaning, that it is a decimal number of 160.

if you type in your resx `&#160;` it will be considered as a `&nbsp;`